# Javascript - my password checker doesn't print anything

Tags: javascript, json, foreach

I'm very new to js. This is my first attempt at something useful. The concept is simple: get a  json array ready, and then foreach loop through it. If it fails at one loop, print an error message. I tried to run this code but nothing happens:

```
var pass = ji3or;
function passCheck {
 var variations = {
                    digits:{ /\d/.test(pass),errorMsg:"Must contain at least 1 digit!"},
                    lower: {/[a-z]/.test(pass),errorMsg:"Must contain at least 1 lower case letter!"},
                    upper: {/[A-Z]/.test(pass),errorMsg:"Must contain at least 1 upper case letter!"},
                    nonWords:{ /\W/.test(pass),errorMsg:"Must contain at least 1 non-letter symbol e.g. "@"!"},
                }

            for (var check in variations) {
                 variations[check] == true ?  : document.write(check.errorMsg);
                }
            }   
           }
           passCheck();
```

Comment: You've got some syntax errors, and probably want `ji3or` as a string. Have you checked your browser's dev tools?

Comment: Have you checked your console? `function passCheck`  is missing `()`; `symbol e.g. "@"!"` has wrong quotes. Ternary operator missing `if-true` statement

Comment: Read a tutorial on javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several syntax errors in your code! - missing quotes, too much brackets etc...

Nevertheless below a corrected snippet of your code that prints your desired behaviour:

```js
var pass = "ji3or"; // strings need to be wrapped in quotes

function passCheck(pass) { // pass a variable to the function instead of relying on the global one
    var variations = {
        // add a proper key to reference it later and make it a valid object
        digits: { isValid: /\d/.test(pass), errorMsg: "Must contain at least 1 digit!" },
        lower: { isValid: /[a-z]/.test(pass), errorMsg: "Must contain at least 1 lower case letter!" },
        upper: { isValid: /[A-Z]/.test(pass), errorMsg: "Must contain at least 1 upper case letter!" },
        nonWords:{ isValid: /\W/.test(pass), errorMsg: "Must contain at least 1 non-letter symbol e.g. '@'!" } // use different quotes and not "@" or escape them with \"
    }

    for (var key in variations) {
        if(!variations[key].isValid) // you dont need a ternary operator, just check for a false value
            document.write(variations[key].errorMsg);
    }   
}

passCheck(pass);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function passCheck(pass){
  if(pass.length<6){
    console.log("password too short")
  }
  else if(!/[A-Z]/.test(pass)){ 
    console.log("must contain uppercase letter")}
    else {
      console.log("all good")
    }
            }   
           
  passCheck("Asadasdasd");
```

your function is written wrong, and that is not the way how you should usually validate password. Here is how i would do it

Comment: Thanks a lot! I forgot the length part!

Comment: Truth be told your code actually makes much much more sense and are more oriented and fitting to this scenario.